# how to dynamically populate select box using jquery in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery

I'm having a problem with php and jQuery, I've been trying to figure this thing out for some time  but I feel I just might be misunderstanding how to get what I need to work. I'm using WordPress but basic php and jQuery coding will work because WordPress consists of both and more. So let me get right to it.

everybody pretty much understands the `foreach` loop in php. This is just my example but it doesn't matter how you do your foreach loop:

```
    $terms = get_terms($tax);
    $x = '<select name="'. $tax .'">';
    $x .= '<option value="">Select '. ucfirst($tax) .'</option>';
    foreach ($terms as $key =>&$term) {
       $x .= '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'
    }
    $x .= '</select>';
    return $x;
```

and in jQuery and php to my understanding doesn't work because they take place on two separate sides. So pretty much let's say I have:

```
<select name="tax">
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

for each select option I wanted them dynamically populated like you would php but in jQuery. Now in jQuery you have `.each` function and then `for()` function you could use.

How would I go about getting all the terms from php that are in an array stored in variable called `$tax` and to populate each option with my terms from my array. Any example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Start by putting your data into json and stuffing them into a variable:

```
var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>
```

Now write it out using jQuery, should look something like this:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

$("#my-form").text("<select>");

$(arrayFromPHP.items).each(function(index, item) {
    form.append(
        $(document.createElement('option')).text(item)
    );
});

$("#my-form").append("</select>");
});
```

Comment: oh okay i see what your doing I'm going to try to attempt this when I'm back near my computer

Comment: this solved my issue i wasnt getting my terms like I wanted too becuse i didn't call each term in get terms function. `function buildSelect($tax){
 
 $terms = get_terms('location');
 $count = count($terms);
 $x = '<select id="select1A" name="location">';
 $x .= '<option value="">Select '. ucfirst('location') .'</option>';?>
 <?php if ( $count --> 0 ){foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $x .= '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
 }}
 $x .= '</select>';
 return $x;
 
}`

Answer (score 0):

what i have understood is that you would like to get the values from php array, into jquery and manipulate those values as you like in Jquery,

to do that i would suggest that you print the $terms array to an array of  JSON objects where you want them to be located in jquery.

Example

```
<script>
var taxArray= <?php toJson($terms) ?>
</script>
```

so when you run the page, after php is excuted it would be something like this:

```
<script>
var taxArray= [{itemName:book,taxPrice:10,TaxPercentage:12}, {itemName:pencil,taxPrice:10,TaxPercentage:12}]
</script>
```

Comment: yes your correct! its been frustrating for while trying figure this out so i decided to send it to stackoverflow.

Comment: for some reason i cant get my box to populate i tested it one that worked in js fiddle but when i apply it to WordPress local host its not coming through for whatever reason. which leads me to think maybe locally i wouldn't be able to see it, only if its live then ill be able to.

Comment: here is one my js fiddle i was messing with http://jsfiddle.net/jtKvn/1/ it returns the values here but when i do this on my localhost it doesn't show

Comment: could you paste the whole html after you run the page on locally?

Comment: sure I will as soon as I can

Comment: I actually solved my issue every thing was actually working just the taxonomy registered name in Wordpress was of by a letter every thing works fine 'm glad, you learned something new everyday. thanks Saad and jappe for helping me out.